# PHP try catch: get variable defined in try

Tags: php, try-catch, scope

I'm trying to debug some code. I want to be able to show variables defined in `try` in `catch`. For example the variable `$siteId`.

```
<?php
try {
    $siteId = 3;
    if(1 !== 2) {
        throw new Exception('1 does not equal 2!');
    }
} catch(Exception $e) {
    $moreInfo = '';
    if(isset($siteId)) {
        $moreInfo .= ' SiteId»' . $siteId;
    }
    echo 'Error' . $moreInfo . ':' . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

The response I get is `Error: 1 does not equal 2!` instead of `Error SiteId»3: 1 does not equal 2!`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Jup, I don't have any problems getting the desired output ("
Error SiteIdÂ»3:1 does not equal 2!")

Comment: Oh. You guys are right! It does work: http://ideone.com/ctbe8q I guess it's something else in my code that's causing the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Works as you expected with all PHP 5 releases - http://3v4l.org/IKODl#tabs

Comment: _"too localized, probably some syntax error elsewhere"_  (reason for close vote)

Comment: Sorry to bother you guys... It has to be something somewhere else in my code. How do I "cancel" this question?

Comment: @iDev247: There's a link that says "delete" under your question.

Comment: You should really consider marking the answer by Naib as the correct one. The other two (which have more votes currently) are incorrect.

Answer (score 13):

Declare $siteId outside the try/catch construct and use `!empty($siteId)` inside the catch.

```
$siteId = null;
try {

}catch(Exceptions $e) {
  if( ! empty($siteId) ) {

  }
}
```

Comment: PHP 5.4: I found out that attempting define a variable within a try block, then trying to access it somewhere outside of the try block will lead to undefined variable notices.

Comment: I think you can also access the variable defined inside the try catch outside of it. https://repl.it/LSz3

Comment: Olotin Temitope. You are in PHP 7.x.x on repl.it. Not the same as PHP 5.4

Answer (score 6):

Variables in PHP are scoped to the file, method or function, (see http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php), so I'm not sure how this isn't working for you. A quick cut-n-paste into PhpStorm outputs the correct response for me.

Answer (score 6):

When using `catch()`, you can't pass context to it using `catch (Exception $e) use($foo)`. So a workaround is to assign the var as a state of the class:

```
private $foo;

try  {

 $foo = 'Foo';
 $this->foo = 'Foo';

} catch (Exception $e) {

   var_dump($foo); // null
   var_dump($this->foo); // 'Foo'

}
```

#### Edit 2022

Coming back to this answer in 2022, I now see different results:

```php
class Foo {
    private $foo_in_class;
    public function do_foo() {
        $outside_foo = null;
        try  {
         $outside_foo = 'Outside Foo';
         $foo_in_try = 'Foo In Try';
         $this->foo_in_class = 'Foo in Class';
         throw new Exception();
        } catch (Exception $e) {
           var_dump($outside_foo);
           var_dump($foo_in_try);
           var_dump($this->foo_in_class);
        }
    }
}
(new Foo)->do_foo();
```

Has the same behavior in all PHP versions (5.4 to 8.2-rc1):

```
Output for 5.4.0 - 5.4.45, 5.5.0 - 5.5.38, 5.6.0 - 5.6.40, 7.0.0 - 7.0.33, 7.1.0 - 7.1.33, 7.2.0 - 7.2.34, 7.3.0 - 7.3.33, 7.4.0 - 7.4.32, 8.0.0 - 8.0.24, 8.1.0 - 8.1.11, 8.2rc1 - rc3
string(11) "Outside Foo"
string(10) "Foo In Try"
string(12) "Foo in Class"
```

So it seems that `$foo` is available in catch after all.

https://3v4l.org/8VYp0

Comment: "protected" and "this" should be used when working with the class, in your case you have not demonstrated the complete code, so please edit the answer to add the complete code of class or mention it in your answer description so that it is more clear to those new to the language.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `\` to `Exception` class. So your code becomes:

```
<?php
try {
    $siteId = 3;
    if(1 !== 2) {
        throw new \Exception('1 does not equal 2!');
    }
} catch(\Exception $e) {
    $moreInfo = '';
    if(isset($siteId)) {
        $moreInfo .= ' SiteId»' . $siteId;
    }
    echo 'Error' . $moreInfo . ':' . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to move out $siteId from try/catch:

```
<?php
$siteId = 3;
try {        
    if(1 !== 2) {
        throw new Exception('1 does not equal 2!');
    }
} catch(Exception $e) {
    $moreInfo = '';
    if(isset($siteId)) {
        $moreInfo .= ' SiteId»' . $siteId;
    }
    echo 'Error' . $moreInfo . ':' . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

Comment: no. what if you do other kind of more complicated, dependent stuff besides a simple variable assignment with a primitive? What if you use a library call that outputs a value depending on another value depending on another value, and you want to inspect the final value in the catch for error logging? This is not a solution.

Things that are outside the try have the downside of being outside the try.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$siteId = 3;
try {

    if(1 !== 2) {
        throw new Exception('1 does not equal 2!');
    }
} catch(Exception $e) {
    $moreInfo = '';
    if(!empty($siteId)) {
        $moreInfo .= ' SiteId»' . $siteId;
    }
    echo 'Error' . $moreInfo . ':' . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```